# Python function with optional "and" condition

Tags: python, function, pyspark

I'm trying to figure out **if it makes sense** to combine below 2 similar functions into 1 (this is more from a practical side - whichever is easier on processing). And if yes, then **how**?

- `get_result_1()`: always needed
- `get_result_2()`: `get_result_1()` + "and" statement with variable column_name & input_value

Functions in question:

```
def get_result_1(item: str, type: str) -> Column:
    c = ((f.col("item") == item) & (f.col("type") == type))
    return c

def get_result_2(item: str, type: str, input_1: str, input_2: str) -> Column:
    c = (get_result_1(item, type)
        & (f.col(input_1) == input_2) #<-- make this part of get_result_1?
    )
return c
```

Use case:

```
output_df = (
    df
    .withColumn("category", 
                f.when(get_result_1("A", "xyz1"), f.lit("C1"))
                .when(get_result_2("B", "xyz2", "level1", "high"), f.lit("C2"))
                .when(get_result_2("B", "xyz3", "level2", "L7"), f.lit("C3"))
               )
)
```

I've been exploring variadic arguments but I'm not able to make it work. At this point I'm questioning if I'm even on the right path.

Comment: From the Spark side it shouldn't matter, as either way it should result in the same query (depends on how you implement it, you can check this with `df.explain()`). From the programming 'convenience' side it might be better to combine. However opinion based questions tend not to do so well on SO.

Comment: @ScootCork thanks for the input, appreciate it. How would you go about combining these 2 functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Spark side it shouldn't matter, as either way it should result in the same query. You can check this with `df.explain()` using the two approaches.

You can combine the two functions by making `input_1` and `input_2` optional and checking if they are passed. You can add some additional checks if you'd like.

```
def get_result(item: str, item_type: str, input_1: str = None, input_2: str = None) -> Column:
    c = ((f.col("item") == item) & (f.col("type") == item_type))

    if input_1:
        c = c & (f.col(input_1) == input_2)

    return c
```